# Is there an equation for the number of ways that n intervals can intersect each other?

Tags: combinatorics

We can denote the left ends by [ and the right ends by ]<sub>i</sub>, where the i refers to the interval starting with the ith [. For n=1 there is one possibility: []<sub>1</sub>.  For n=2, < are 3 possibilities: []<sub>1</sub>[]<sub>2</sub>, [[]<sub>1</sub>]<sub>2</sub> and [[]<sub>2</sub>]<sub>1</sub>.

The total number of possibilities is obviously less than (2n)!  For n > 1, it is also greater than n!, since for n ['s in a row, there are n! ways of permuting the ]<sub>i</sub>'s.

Comment: Why is that $[]_2[]_1$ is not counted?

Comment: @Phicar You cannot close an interval that you have not opened yet. $]_2$ should close the second interval, but you have only started one interval. Note that $[]_1[]_2$ _is_ counted.

Comment: This is not a perfect answer to your question, but a closely related question is that of counting [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).  The answer to your question will be strictly greater than that of the $n$'th Catalan number since the catalan numbers count your arrangements but with all indices of closing brackets specifically being in increasing order.  (*equivalently, where we don't label the closing brackets*)

Comment: @Phicar I was also confused at first, but note the indices refer to the $i$th `[` bracket. If we add these indices on the left brackets, the three possibilities are $[_1 ]_1 [_2 ]_2$ (disjoint), $[_1 [_2 ]_1 ]_2$ (partial overlap), and $[_1 [_2 ]_2 ]_1$ (subset). The order of the intervals doesn't matter.

Comment: Are $[[]_2]_1 []_3$ and $[]_1 [[]_3]_2$ the same (order of disjoint partitions doesn't matter) or different (order in real line matters, though labeling doesn't matter)?

Comment: The two examples you gave would be considered different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let $a_n$ be the number of ways $n$ intervals with distinct labels can intersect. This is equivalent to the number of sequences of length $2n$ containing each of the integers from $1$ to $n$ exactly twice, since the two positions of $i$ in order correspond to the positions of the left and right ends of the interval labeled $i$.

$$ a_n = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2n(2n-1)}{2} = n! \cdot (2n-1)!! $$

(where $k!!$ is the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), e.g. $7!! = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$)

But $a_n$ counts each way $n$ intervals *without* distinct labels can intersect $n!$ different times. So the desired answer is

$$ \frac{a_n}{n!} = (2n-1)!! $$

(As a check, for $n=3$ we have:

$$ \begin{array}{ccccc}
[]_1 []_2 []_3 & []_1 [[]_2 ]_3 & []_1 [[]_3]_2 & [[]_1]_2 []_3 & [ []_1 []_2 ]_3 \\
[[]_1 []_3]_2 & [[[]_1]_2]_3 & [[[]_1]_3]_2 & [[[]_3]_1]_2 & [[]_2]_1 []_3 \\
[[]_2[]_1]_3 & [[]_2 []_3]_1 & [[[]_2 []_1]_3 & [[[]_2 []_3]_1 & [[[]_3]_2]_1
\end{array} $$
and $(2n-1)!! = 5!! = 15$.)

Comment: Thank you!  It is surprising how simple the formula is.  I wrote a short horribly inefficient program to check the next few cases and the program agreed with the formula.